# How to get column index which is matching with specific value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe as below.

```
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
    True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
    [1 rows * 8 columns]
```

As you can see, there is one `True` value which is the first column.

Therefore, I want to get the `0` index which is `True` element in the dataframe.
In other case, there is `True` in the 4th column index, then I would like to get the `4` as 4th column has the `True` value for below dataframe.

```
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
    False  False  False  False  True  False  False  False
    [1 rows * 8 columns]
```

I tried to google it but failed to get what I want.
And for assumption, there is no designated column name in the case.

Look forward to your help.

Thanks.

Comment: do you always have only 1 row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking for `idxmax`:

```
>>> df
      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
0  True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False

>>> df.idxmax(axis=1)
0    0
dtype: object
```

```
>>> df
       0      1      2      3     4      5      6      7
0  False  False  False  False  True  False  False  False

>>> df.idxmax(axis=1)
0    4
dtype: object
```

**Caveat**: if all values are `False`, Pandas returns the first index because index 0 is the lowest index of the highest value:

```
>>> df
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
0  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False

>>> df.idxmax(axis=1)
0    0
dtype: object
```

**Workaround**: replace `False` by `np.nan`:

```
>>> df.replace(False, np.nan).idxmax(axis=1)
0   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want every field that is true:

```
cols_true = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in cols:
        if row[i]:
            cols_true.append(i)
print(cols_true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean indexing:

```
df.columns[df.iloc[0]]
```

output:

```
Index(['0'], dtype='object')
```

Or `numpy.where`

```
np.where(df)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to index the dataframe's index by a column itself (`0` in this case), as follows:

```py
df.index[df[0]]
```

You'll get:

```
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df.loc[:, df.any()].columns[0]
# 4
```

If you have several `True` values you can also get them all with `columns`

**Generalization**

Imagine we have the following dataframe (several True values in positions 4, 6 and 7):

```
       0      1      2      3     4      5     6     7
0  False  False  False  False  True  False  True  True
```

With the formula above :

```py
df.loc[:, df.any()].columns
# Int64Index([4, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.apply(lambda ss:ss.loc[ss].index.min(),axis=1).squeeze()
```

out：

```
0
```

or

```
df1.loc[:,df1.iloc[0]].columns.min()
```